# Is it Pythonic to have global functions not part of a class?

Tags: python

In my test suite I have a file called "utils.py" in which I have assorted functions required by many of the tests.  To accomplish this I created a "Utils" class and had all of the functions inside it.

A colleague, with more Python experience, insisted that there should be no such class and instead all of these functions should be top-level.  Thus "Utils.get_feature_id()" became "get_feature_id()".

Would you concur with his assertion?

Robert

Comment: It's largely a matter of personal preference (and consistency with the rest of the project etc). If the class exists solely for grouping functions, I personally would side with your colleague and argue that the module is a better unit of encapsulation.

Comment: I agree with @NPE.

Comment: Python is not Java. You do not need to stick everything in a class.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I would agree with your colleague. If you find yourself recreating what might be termed a "static class" in Java, for example, then just forget about the class and make module-level functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the only thing you are using the `class` for is to essentially have the "methods" within a namespace. I agree with your coworker, you could have these functions be top level, but kept in a module so they indeed get put in a namespace, e.g.

```
import utils
utils.get_feature_id()
```

Instead of the following, which would presume you marked all your methods as `@staticmethod` which again just adds an unnecessary layer.

```
import utils
utils.Utils.get_feature_id()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If a function doesn't access a `self`, it should most likely not be a method. You can use a full module if your goal was to arrange your functions in a distinct namespace. Python uses namespaces everywhere, so we need not shy away from global names like C++ tends to and Java enforces (effectively, because they're not that global after all).